# Ask turtles to visit random turtles in different ticks

Tags: netlogo

I have these agentsets called collectors and bins, collectors visit bins once a day (each tick is equal to one hour). But they will keep visiting the same bin on the other days. 
I would like to make them on the next day to visit a random different bin, but I do not know how to ask that. Could someone help me, please. 
Here is the command where I ask this command.

```
to search-bins-to-collect

ask one-of collectors [move-to one-of [ bins in-radius 10] of myself]

 collect-waste

end
```

The number of collectors will vary during the year and I can not tell them the exact number of the turtle.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say "I would like to make them on the next day to visit a random different bin" but you also say "I want to make one collector to be responsible by one bin throughout the days".  These sound contradictory.  Please rephrase.

Comment: Thank you you all, but I figured studying NetLogo's programing guide.